# Plotting probabilities from firth's logistic regression with ordinal predictor in R

Tags: r, logistic, data-visualization, ordinal-data

I have fit a model using firth's logistic regression.

```
library(logistf)

Model <- logistf(a~b, data = data)
```

Where b is an ordinal variable with 3 levels. Therefore the summary of the model looks like this

```
                       coef  se(coef) lower 0.95 upper 0.95       Chisq            p
(Intercept)            0.3     0.37    -0.57        0.9            0.44           0.50
b.L                     3      0.8      0.83        3.8            11             0.005
b.Q                     4      0.5     -1.2         0.8            0.05            0.9
```

**PLEASE NOTE**
L and Q in this summary refer to linear and quadratic components of the model. L and Q do not refer to categories of b.

Plotting this model as shown in this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41384075/r-calculate-and-interpret-odds-ratio-in-logistic-regression

Will not make sense, as the x axis only has 3 points (1 for each category). Is there an alternative approach to modelling this sort of model?

Perhaps just to report the probabilities for each 3 categories.

Comment: What do you want to go on the x-axis? You also only have three points, so that cannot yield a nice curve.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov  Thats a good point I hadn't thought about. I've modified the question in response.